# VSTO 4: How detect TAB is visible/chosen?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsto, outlook-addin

Do you know how can I detect when my Outlook AddIn TAB is visible/selected at some moment?

My problem: sometimes users press the Outlook default SEND button instead my own SEND button (required for some posterior processing) and I would like to detect it to call the user's attention.

The problem is also that, users CAN press the default SEND button for messages not related/addressed to some recipients...

Objectively: if the user is, at the moment, in my TAB, I send a MessageBox to him, otherwise I don't.

Thank you!

Comment: The only way to detect what's going on in Ribbon tabs is to use the Accessibility interface. Useful links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb404170(v=office.12), http://www.wordarticles.com/Shorts/RibbonVBA/RibbonVBADemo.php, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2494267/how-to-call-active-accessibility-apis-to-develop-automation-for-office. Beyond that Ribbon XML has a `commands` section that can be used to re-purpose built-in controls (msoId) so that you could detect when the user clicks default "Send".

Comment: Thanks Cindy but I see that docs are not eligible to my problem. I'm using Office 2010 AddIn (I suppose be different from 2010); I'm not using VBA but XML .NET VSTO 4; my interface is in Outlook, which differs from Word and Excel; and a lot of docs that refer to "Ribbon1...." to access interface from Code simply do not function. I read in some places exactly this: VBA can access the Ribbon but .NET does not.  Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: The Accessibility interface is language-independent. I included Tony's link becaue the explanation is easy to understand. The other suggestion - using a `commands` section in your Ribbon, is pure Ribbon XML.